# How do I convert 50Hz AC to 60Hz AC using a cyclo-converter?

Tags: frequency, inverter, converter, thyristor

I want to design a 3 phase cyclo-converter to run a 7.5kW induction motor. The input to the cyclo-converter is 50Hz AC and the output of the cyclo-converter should be 60Hz AC.

What are the specific ratings of thyristors for designing the above?

Comment: "Hz" not "hz". Why not buy a 3 phase motor speed controller?

Comment: Why not just use a frequency drive? it can vary the Hz, 50/60.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Wikipedia's page on cycloconverters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloconverter), firstly they are only used for producing a lower frequency. Secondly, they are only financially sensible at megawatt powers.

As for thyristors' ratings, they will be in their respective datasheets.

A [Google search for "50Hz to 60Hz"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=50hz%20to%2060hz%20converter) gives a plethora of options for achieving what you want. There are plenty of off-the-shelf solutions as well as cheaper home-brew methods.